# Good explanation of Haralick's labeling algorithm

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, labeling

How would you explain Haralick's labeling algorithm (with foreword and backward iterations)?

Comment: Have you tried looking for some literature and reading it? I recommend doing this. Then, if you're having difficulties understanding what you're reading, ask a question on [cs.se].

Comment: I've searched in several articles and book, but I can't find a good explanation on how it works. Can you suggest some references?

Comment: Have you checked Haralick's publications? His book? [Searching](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=haralick+labeling)? If the papers you find are way over your head, find, ask for explanations.